# Best way to reference a keyfile in nodejs

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, private-key

I did some searching, but my terms "keyfile reference secure" and various others turned up too many results, so here I am. If this has been asked before, I'd be happy to reference that.

I have a nodejs project that uses the [Google Vision API/SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision#readme) and that sample project uses the `google-cloud` module and then uses this kind of structure to get the key file (reference [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cloud-nodejs/blob/8d2578696549ccc4b2cf84cdae83bed6b23fda3e/step-3-book-cover-images/books.js)

```
  var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

  var datastore = gcloud.datastore({
    projectId: config.projectId,
    keyFilename: config.keyFilename
  });
```

However, when using the `@google-cloud/vision` module directly, you can also use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to a file containing the key file and it "just works" as long as you export the environment variable or set the variable and initiate the command like so:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/jomama/somefolder/keyfile.json node
```

So, considering the project will be tracked with git, my questions are:

1. What is the code level advantage of using either approach in the above?
2. What security issues need to be addressed in either approach?
3. Any other considerations I'm missing?

Granted I don't want my keyfile stored in git but I still want the project tracked there.